# eosio: assertion failure with message: datastream attempted to read past the end

Tags: eosio.token, eosio.cdt

Im getting this error "**eosio: assertion failure with message: datastream attempted to read past the end**" when i try to call transfer function from another mine smart contract.

```
void simplenft::test(name receiver, const asset qty) {
      eosio::action(
          eosio::permission_level{get_self() , "active"_n },
          "MYCONTRACTNAME"_n, "transfer"_n,
          std::make_tuple( 
          get_self(), 
          receiver, 
          qty, 
          std::string("sent"))
      ).send();
}
```

Comment: I had this error in the case of trying to use `eosio::unpack` where the unpacker threw this as a result of not including the final byte of a `std::string` value.  EOSIO adds a length prefix onto the string with LEB128 encoding.  Credit to Todd https://t.me/c/1139062279/285824

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: Yes,
string memo = "";
std::string sym = "PLA";
const asset quantity = asset{ 10000, symbol{"PLA", 4} };

      eosio::action(
          eosio::permission_level{get_self() , "active"_n },
          "MYCONTRACTNAME"_n, "transfer"_n,
          std::make_tuple( 
          get_self(), 
          receiver, 
          quantity , 
          memo )
      ).send();